# Lipschitzness of derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Let $f \in C^\infty_b(\mathbb{R}^d; \mathbb{R}^d)$, so bounded, infinitely differentiable with bounded derivatives mapping $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$. I'll write $|\cdot|$ for the norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$  as well as the induced operator norm. By boundedness, we have a $B_1 > 0$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$
$$|Df(x)|\leq B_1$$
this immediately gives that $\forall x,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ 
$$|Df(x)y_1 - Df(x)y_2| \leq B_1 |y_1 - y_2|.$$
Is it possible (maybe using boundedness of $D^2f$ + MVE) to obtain that there exists $L_1 > 0$ such that $\forall x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$
$$|Df(x_1)y_1 - Df(x_2)y_2| \leq L_1 |y_1 - y_2|.$$
Similarly can this be done for higher order derivatives say
$$|Df^2(x_1)[y_1,y_1] - Df^2(x_2)[y_2,y_2]| \leq L_2 |y_1 - y_2|^2.$$
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That would be quite peculiar: then $Df(x_1)=Df(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2$... :)

Comment: Yeah... hummm. Maybe something less like $|Df(x_1)y_1 -  Df(x_2)y_2| \leq L_1 |x_1-x_2||y_1-y_2|$?

Comment: First: you should tell us what you have in mind to ask this. Second: you should make some effort, really, does it look like a norm what you just wrote? You see, we know well what should be expected, you need to think about it instead of guessing.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm guessing because I don't know the answer; this is not some homework problem. What I want is a bound on $|Df(x_1)y_1 - Df(x_2)y_2|$ in terms of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ and constants with w/e necessary assumptions on $f$. What I can get, for example, is by boundedness of $D^2f$, $Df$ is Lipschitz so there is an $L_1$ such that $|Df(x_1)-Df(x_2)| \leq L_1 |x_1-x_2|$ then $|(Df(x_1)-Df(x_2))(y_1-y_2)|\leq L_1 |x_1-x_2||y_1-y_2|$, but this not quite what I want. I was thinking of adding and subtracting something to the original to get this, but I can't quite see it.